# Grouping substrings with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

I'm new to xsl transforms and having trouble with grouping substrings. I have some xml like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document-root>
  <classes>
    <class1>CATSryverty</class1>
    <class1>CATSt6vvy</class1>
    <class1>CATS4yv6v</class1>
    <class1>DOGSrybytb</class1>
    <class1>DOGSbu6b</class1>
    <class1>DOGS5u57756</class1>
  </classes>
</document-root>
```

and this xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <docs>
        <xsl:for-each select="document-root/classes">
            <xsl:element name="classesCSV">
                <xsl:for-each select="class1/text()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 4)"/>
                    <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </docs>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And that gets me this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<docs>
 <classesCSV>CATS,CATS,CATS,DOGS,DOGS,DOGS</classesCSV>
</docs>
```

But what I'd like is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<docs>
 <classesCSV>CATS,DOGS</classesCSV>
</docs>
```

How should I change it?

Comment: Well, you tagged this with Muenchian grouping, but you're not doing any.

Comment: I've seen it mentioned regarding grouping and don't understand it, but thought it might be relevant here. I'm not sure how to combine the results of substring into grouping to get the result I need.

Comment: It is  very relevant here. See: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: In any question about XSLT, and especially one about grouping, you need to say whether you can use XSLT 2.0 or whether you're constrained to 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="kDistinct" match="class1" use="substring(., 1,4)"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <docs>
    <xsl:for-each select="document-root/classes">
       <xsl:element name="classesCSV">
          <xsl:for-each select="class1[generate-id() = 
                          generate-id(key('kDistinct', substring(.,1,4))[1])]">
             <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,4)"/>
             <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </docs>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<docs>
  <classesCSV>CATS,DOGS</classesCSV>
</docs>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <docs>
   <xsl:element name="classesCSV">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//class1" group-by="substring(., 1,4)">
         <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
         <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:element>
  </docs>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```